# ubuntu, building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): still running takes forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, web-applications

Currnetly, I am working on a little django webapp project and

making instance in AWS Lightsail.

When I ' $ sudo docker-compose up -d --build ' in Ubuntu(18.04 LTS) terminal

evreything else looks fine until I see 'building wheel for cryptography(PEP 517): still running'

and there, it takes more than 10 to 20 mintues until the terminal lose connection.

so I am not sure what is the problem here...

What would possibly cause this problem?

Comment: Did you find a root cause for this? I see this issue in a different context. For me, wheel finally builds after about 9 minutes of time.